# Android studio 0.8 setup Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have download Android Studio 0.8.1 from [here.](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)

After that i have copied sdk folder from old version.

But I am getting following error when i am opening My project which i have created previously.

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Is there any setting for update new android studio?

You help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You Can download Android studio bundle here:
  https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html
   Note:Don't Open your existing project ,Import your project then only gradle can update .
Solution 1: After Install Android Studio goto file->default configuration->Location select your old sdk then restart your android studio.[image: Android SDK Location]